# WPF c# DataGrid value changes are not notified cell by cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, notify

I have a datagrid with data bound with an Observable collection of objects which implement InotifyChanged. When i select an item in the data grid, the selection unit should be the entire row (not cell by cell). However, when i update a cell and navigates to the other cell using the "tab" key, the change on the previous cell should be saved (or the PropertyChangedEvents should be triggered). Is there a way to achieve this?

Additional notes:

- I've tried with UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus and this works fine. But once the change is saved, the current cell is not highlighted (editable). I had to click on the cell again using the mouse to get the focus.
- I tried to use the SelectionCellsChanged event but this is not triggered while navigating through cells when the selectionMode is row

Comment: Could you provide some code? DataGrid and Observable collection objects.

Comment: Hi I found out that this is due to an issue in the Observable collection which is a custom one. Thanks for having a look at this